# Xamarin Build Error on virtualized Windows Visual Studio on macbook pro

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, virtualbox

I have a macbook pro and I need to do some stuff with Xamarins' Forms project on Windows Visual Studio, so I use VirtualBox and installed Windows 10 pro.

I cloned the project on my windows machine, cleaned it, but when I try to rebuild I get this error:
(Is not a code error, the same project compiles in other machines, I guess is some settings problem.)

```
Error       The "Aapt" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument..ctor(String templateFilename, TaskLoggingHelper log)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.GenerateCommandLineCommands()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.ExecuteForAbi(String abi)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() DemoAzureOfflineSync.Droid
```

Comment: it sounds like there may be a bad character in your Android manifest

Comment: You can use 'Visual Studio for Mac', using it on a daily basis without critical issues.